# PHP not moving files from /tmp to target dir

Tags: php, linux, apache2, lamp

Trying to create a simple file depository on a LAMP stack, but whenever I upload files they won't move from /tmp to target dir.

I can't workout where I'm going wrong, I'm using the example code from the PHP docs:

```
<?php

    $uploaddir='/var/www/example.com/public_html/uploads/';
    $uploadfile=$uploaddir.basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    echo'<pre>';
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile))
    {
        echo"File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }

    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);

    print "</pre>";

?>

<!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">

    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />

    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />

    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

Browser output is:

```
Possible file upload attack!
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test_File.txt
            [full_path] => Test_File.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php1hAD8G
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 19
        )

)
```

and the apache error log gives the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/var/www/example.com/public_html/uploads/Test_File.txt): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Which I assume means that the system doesn't believe it has permission to create the file in teh target dir. when I set up the site I used:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example.com/public_html/uploads
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/
```

and I can see that the files are owned by whatever account I'm logged into on the SSH as.

I'm pretty new to this, but I assume I've done everything right here but I've made a mistakes with the permissions?

SOLUTION: Follow stefket's advice to change the permissions it's now working as intended.

Comment: The web server is probably running under a different user. Allow write access for other users for the uploads directory by running the following command: `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/example.com/public_html/uploads`

Comment: Wouldn't this enable all users to run code in directory? I wondering if that would create a security risk?

Comment: That would enable, that every user can write to this directory. But we are talking about system users and not about website users.

For security reasons your upload script should check the uploaded file before copying. So that, for example, no one can upload a php script that he could then call up via the browser.